# Adding events to device calendar using Ionic framework

Tags: angularjs, date, mobile, cross-platform, ionic-framework

I'm creating a cross platform mobile app using Ionic framework and AngularJS
In this app I need to get a date string and add it to the device's native calendar, is there a way to do so using only Ionic and AngularJS?
and if there's no way to do so, can you tell me if there's a way doing so without them?
Thank You !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the Angular wrapper for Cordova calendar:
http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/calendar/

Once you add ngCordova to your app.js and install the calendar plugin, you can inject $cordovaCalendar into your controller, then call it like this:

```
  $scope.createEvent = function(event){
    // Add to calendar interactively (vs silently):
    $cordovaCalendar.createEventInteractively({
      title: event.summary,
      location: event.location,
      notes: event.description,
      startDate: startsAt,
      endDate: endsAt
      // startDate: new Date(2015, 0, 6, 18, 30, 0, 0, 0),
      // endDate: new Date(2015, 1, 6, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    }).then(function (result) {
      // success
    }, function (err) {
      // alert('Oops, something went wrong');
    });
  }
```

Comment: Actually, new Date() constructor with 8 parameters did not work, when I tried this. Or maybe I am using the wrong Date object? But I had to remove the last zero.
Only thing is now, when I debug with 'ionic serve' and in browser, I see the startDate and endDate are filled correctly. But when I actually connect to my phone with 'ionic run android', All information is added in the event, except from the date and time. (Not sure if I should start a new question for this, here on stackoverflow, because I still haven't found a solution or an answer on why this doesn't work.)

Comment: I am facing issue Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaCalendarProvider <- $cordovaCalendar <- ExampleController  and on endDate: new Date(2015, 1, 6, 12, 0, 0, 0, 0)